# No encuentro la conexión a DB

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una base de datos que tiene usuarios para que se logueen en un portal y ya me había quedado, pero reinicie mi computadora y ya no funciona. Mi portal pide correo y contraseña al usuario, el error que me sale es el siguiente:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Table 'crm_ventas_conduit.usuarios_login' doesn't exist in engine in C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\consulta_usuario.php:21
> Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\consulta_usuario.php(21): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'SELECT * FROM...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\consulta_usuario.php on line 21

ya verifique mi DB y sí está bien.

Comment: Te estaras conectado a otra base? el error dice que ahi no esta esa tabla...

Comment: O estás entrando con otro usuario, en otra BD donde esa tabla no está